# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #5

Tags: visual, rebus

Who is this actress or character from The Twilight Zone TOS?

[image: l]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

> The actress Morgan Brittany. Credited as a child actress on The Twilight Zone under her real name, Suzanne Cupito. (from Suzanne Vega + Cupid)

Comment: Suzanne Vega + Cupid + the letter O, to be precise! Thanks, Lanny!